# Callback after iterating through an array and saving objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I need to iterate through an array and save every object to the Database.

At the end I need a callback with an `array` of all of the saved and failed object.

Below is the code I have:

```
exports.addList = (app, body, callback) => {
var savedObjects = []
var failedObjects = []

body.forEach((element, index) => {
    body[index] = _.pick(element, 'userAId','userBId')

    db.List.create(element).then((list) => {
        savedObjects.push(element)
         if (index == body.length - 1) {
            callback(savedObjects, failedObjects)
        }
    }).catch((error) => {
        if (error.name === "SequelizeUniqueConstraintError") {
            failedObjects.push(element)
             if (index == body.length - 1) {
            callback(savedObjects, failedObjects)
        }
    })
})
}
```

The code above works.  Is there a way better to accomplish this?

Comment: What don't you like about how it works now? It might be worth posting this to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) as well.

Comment: This seems a reasonable way to achieve what you need. If you want to cut some repetition, you can put your complete check in a single `finally` call at the end of your promise chain and remove it from your `then` and `catch` handlers.

Comment: Thanks.  I am new to javascript and wasn't sure if this is the right way. @JordanBurnett I'll refactor to keep the code DRY.

Comment: @JordanBurnett I thought `finally` wasn't in spec? OP might need to make sure that it exists in whatever environment they're working in.

Comment: @JesseKernaghan OP is using Sequelize, which does include `finally` in its promise implementation.  Good to note though that this isn't true for all Javascript promises.

Comment: @JordanBurnett if you have time to write an answer, I can mark it as answered.

Comment: @user1107173 done - you probably also want to change your complete check, see my answer for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example your complete callback will always fire after the first promise is complete.  This is because the `create` function is asynchronous while the surrounding loop is not, therefore the loop will have already completed by the time your first callback is triggered.

In your scenario this means `element` and `index` will always be the last in the loop. One way around this would be to move your promise chain into it's own function.

In this example I've used an extra flag to track the number of completed promises to trigger your `complete` method.

```
exports.addList = (app, body, callback) => {
  var savedObjects = []
  var failedObjects = []
  var complete = 0;

  function createElement(element){
    db.List.create(element).then((list) => {
        savedObjects.push(element)
    }).catch((error) => {
        if (error.name === "SequelizeUniqueConstraintError") {
            failedObjects.push(element)
        }
    }).finally(() => {
        complete++;
        if(complete == body.length) {
          callback(savedObjects, failedObjects)
        }
    });
  }

  body.forEach((element, index) => {
    body[index] = _.pick(element, 'userAId','userBId');
    createElement(element);
  })
}
```

Comment: You can also do this in a `Promise.all().then()` if you want the `db.List.create()` to run in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the following approach using [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to run the `db.List.create()` in parallel as it will return a `Promise`. By [mapping](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the `body` array elements to `Promises` you can achieve better performance as they will run in parallel (and not have to track the `complete` count).

```js
exports.addList = (app, body, callback) => {
  var savedObjects = [];
  var failedObjects = [];

  Promise.all(
    // map the array to return Promises
    body.map(element => {
      const list = _.pick(element, 'userAId','userBId');
      return db.List.create(list)
      .then(() => savedObjects.push(list))
      .catch((error) => {
        if (error.name === 'SequelizeUniqueConstraintError') {
          failedObjects.push(list)
        }
      })
    })
  )
  // when all Promises have resolved return the callback
  .then(() => callback(savedObjects, failedObjects));
}
```